# Why python makes the difference between expressions and statements?

Tags: python

1. What are the reasons for putting the border between expressions and statements in python? Are there any limitations that require that distinction?
2. What is the benefit for the python programmers?

Comment: Many languages differentiate statements from expressions. Maybe you have a specific example in mind that only applies to Python?

Comment: @Frédéric It's true; differentiating expressions and statements is the norm. But a lot of dynamic language these days (Javascript, R) don't make the distinction, or blur it heavily. So I guess the question could be, why didn't Python follow this trend?

Comment: I know _why_ statically typed imperative languages do that. I'm curious about the reasons behind python choice.

Comment: @Owen, I don't know R (yet), but Javascript sure has statements. What do you think `for`, `if` and `while` are? :)

Comment: @Owen: Python is older than R and Javascript, so it could hardly follow their design flaws^H^H^H^H^Hdecisions.

Comment: @Frédéric The difference is that they're also expressions, e.g. `var x = if (1) { 2 } else { 3 }`. In Python you'd use different syntax for branching in an expression.

Comment: @Owen, `var x = if (1) { 2 } else { 3 };` raises a syntax error. What kind of Javascript interpreter allows you to use `if` like that?

Comment: @Frédéric Oh... I just tested it in Firefox, but maybe... I don't know?

Comment: @Frédéric Oh ok, what I actually tested was echoing `if (1) { 2 } else { 3 }` which does result in a value... but apparently you can't assign that value to a var... so it's somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @Owen, indeed, you cannot assign the result of `if` to a variable because it's a statement, not an expression :)

Comment: @Frédéric Ah ok, been too long since I've done Javascript, thought it was more functional than it was.

Answer (score 4):

One benefit is that Python programmers don't have to maintain code such as:

```
while((x = foo()) != value)
```